# Pre Filling SharePoint Field using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest

I am using REST API to create a list item in another list. Based on the successful creation of the list item I am just updating the current SharePoint field value. This whole process is executing through `PreSaveAction()` method.

Here I am able to pre fill list column, but after saving the list item the pre fill column is empty.

Here is my Code:

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
    createListItemThroughRESTAPI();
    $('input[id*="<'id Name'>"]').attr('value','Test Value');
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to update the created item with test value? Then you need to get the item and set value to that item. Your JS code will not update the list item.

Comment: Yes,I want to update the created item with the above value.How to achieve this requirement through JS code.

Comment: May be the current item getting saved  before the value got populated into field. Createlistitemthroughrestapi, is it synchronous?

Comment: Yes,I am able to populate the value into the field through Createlistitemthroughrestapi(Custom Method which is used to create item on another list).But after the item saved into the list,the populated value is missing.But this is not happening to default title field.

Answer (score 0):

To create List item using Rest call, you need to do the following:

1) Set the metadata properties as-

```
var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": newItemTitle
    };
```

2) Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
```

Source Reference : https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/create-retrieve-update-and-delete-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-and-jquery/